# PDF Print appears completely different on different devices (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying to create a PDF file based on user input on a website. On my local machine, and after deployment everything works great. However, when I asked my friend to test the PDF, it looked completely different and did not seem to use any of the styles that I provided.

The code isn't complicated, I just passed a CSS class that breaks the next elements into the next page (whenever it was necessary):

CSS

```
@media print {
  @page {
    size: auto;
    margin: 25mm 0;
  }
 
  .pageBreakAfter {
    page-break-after: always;
}
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
   <div>
      first element
   </div>
   <div class='pageBreakAfter'>
      2nd element
   </div>
   <div>
      3rd element
   </div>
</div>
```

My friend and I both have Windows 11 and the newest Chrome. On my machine, the page-break-after css works, but on his it doesn't. How can I fix this?